# Subscribed Functionality 'supportResettableProperties' was added with no resettable properties set

Tags: visual-studio-code, powerapps

i am quite new to Powerapps and creating components. First i tried to create a component while i try to copy this [this Blog](https://blog.thenetw.org/2019/06/06/getting-react-and-office-ui-fabric-work-with-powerapps-component-framework) because i got it recommended and wanted to see how it works. I understood everything until the component is supposed to be started after calling the render method.

The Developer Command Prompt for VS 2019 and the Debugger get me the Error Message:

```
[14:25:3] [start]  Initializing...  
[14:25:3] [start]  Validating manifest...  
[14:25:3] [start]  Failed:  
[pcf-1055] [Error] Subscribed Functionality 'supportResettableProperties' was added with no resettable properties set.
```

I haven't found anything to this Error message and would need a bit of help.

Answer (score 0):

The error is because of library node in controlmanifest.xml

```
 <library name="React" version=">=1" order="1">
    <packaged_library path="../node_modules/react/umd/react.production.min.js" version="16.8.6" />
  </library>
```

The way dependency gets declared got changed. To fix the error, remove above node from controlmanifest.xml and then add dependency to react in packages.json in your control project and do import these in ts file.

like

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is a little old but I am adding an answer since I ran into the same problem and couldn't find a solution online.

This error occurs due to the following check in `manifestSchemaValidator.js` in the `pcf-scripts` library:

```
if (resourceType === 'library' && !this.featureManager.isFeatureEnabled('pcfAllowLibraryResources'))
{
    this.logValidationError(diagnosticMessages_generated_1.strings.validation_support_resettable_with_no_resettable_props);
}
```

To fix this you'll need to enable `pcfAllowLibraryResources`. Add a file called  `featureconfig.json` to the root directory of your control (sibling of package.json) with the following contents

```
{
    "pcfAllowLibraryResources": "on"
}
```

This should fix your build.